# using num.toFixed();

Tags: javascript

In the function below, where would I include num.toFixed(2); to make the valuer of 'total' display to 2 decimal places (price)?

```
function calculate_total(id) {
   var theForm = document.getElementById( id )
   total = 0;
   if (theForm.toyCar.checked) {
      total += parseFloat(theForm.toyCar.value);
   } 
   theForm.total.value = total;
   theForm.GrandTotal.value = total + (total*0.18);
}
```

This is the output:

```
<input type="button" name="CheckValue" value = "Calculate cost" onclick="calculate_total(this.form.id)" />
&nbsp;
Total: <input type="text" name="total" id="total" size="10" readonly="readonly" />
```

Comment: Where you are outputting it?

Answer (score 0):

```
theForm.total.value = total.toFixed(2);
theForm.GrandTotal.value = (total + (total*0.18)).toFixed(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change it in two places to ensure both numbers are formatted to two decimal places:

```
function calculate_total(id) {
    var theForm = document.getElementById( id )
    total = 0;
    if (theForm.toyCar.checked) {
        total += parseFloat(theForm.toyCar.value);
    } 
    theForm.total.value = total.toFixed(2);
    theForm.GrandTotal.value = (total + (total*0.18)).toFixed(2);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In `num.toFixed()`, `num` is the actual numeric expression that wish to affect. You run the `toFixed` function *on* that expression.

So, here you might apply it to `total + (total*0.18)`:

```
theForm.GrandTotal.value = (total + (total*0.18)).toFixed(2);
```

However, **don't**. Don't truncate your values here, or you are introducing potential rounding errors in your code by *significantly* limiting the amount of precision.

This could be deliberate (depending on the manner in which you wish to handle sub-penny values in your calculations) and, if it is, then you should also apply it to the normal `total` value:

```
theForm.total.value = total.toFixed(2);
```

Otherwise, apply this formatting when you *output* the value! i.e., elsewhere:

```
alert(theForm.GrandTotal.value.toFixed(2));
// (or something other than `alert`)
```

Comment: does .tofixed(2); round up to 2 decimal places?

Comment: @Joel: Yes. Why do you want to use it if you don't even know what it does? Read [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed).